# New users should be able to give some sort of feedback on improvements they've requested

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

I made an improvement request that was addressed by [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/drafts/28899). The edit itself addressed my request, but it could have been a bit better formatted by differentiating between versions using [inline versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#inline-versions). However, I'm not able to say anything about it by commenting, propose edits to that draft, or approve or reject the edit. **As a new user, my only option is to wait.** That strikes me as a bit "fire and forget" — I can request an edit, but I can do nothing about it afterwards — and I believe new users should be able to *at least* leave comments on improvements that are made in response to their own improvement requests (unless there's a better way for them to provide feedback to whomever is addressing their improvement request).

The only way I found to fix that (aside from waiting 'till someone approved the edit and then proposing my own on top of it), was to [propose an improvement myself](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/34724) — not with the intention of taking reputation from the user who had suggested the other improvement, but of fixing it (in fact, I pointed to the other improvement in mine's summary).